# Как в анализаторе roslyn проверять параметры метода?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Пробую писать небольшой анализатор roslyn, который бы выполнял некоторую проверку параметров вызываемых методов.

В принципе, что именно анализровать понятно - написал образец кода в linqpad, посмотрел как выглядит дерево:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new Foo();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Foo
{
    public void Bar(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        var query = "UPDATEdbo.test SET Title = 'Abc' WHERE 1 = 1 and Id = 42";
        var rowCount = ExecuteNonQuery(conn, query);
    }
    
    public int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlConnection conn, string query)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но проблема в том, что у меня проблема даже в самой первой строке - там где я пытаюсь конвертировать тип контекста:

```
    private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var expression = context.Symbol as InvocationExpressionSyntax;

        if (expression == null)
            return;

        ...
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> Error CS0039  Cannot convert type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISymbol' to
> 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.InvocationExpressionSyntax' via
> a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion,
> wrapping conversion, or null type
> conversion    Analyzer1   C:\Temp\analyz01\src\Analyzer1\Analyzer1\AnalyzerFormatForSqlQuery.cs   34  Active

Что я делаю не так? Как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Ну да, всё [оказалось](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix) просто: это надо смотреть контекст узла:

```
    private void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var invocationExpression = context.Node as InvocationExpressionSyntax;

        if (invocationExpression == null)
            return;

        var methodSymbol = ModelExtensions.GetSymbolInfo(context.SemanticModel, invocationExpression).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;

        if (methodSymbol == null)
            return;

        if (!methodSymbol.Name.Equals("ExecuteNonQuery"))
            return;

        ...

        var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, invocationExpression.GetLocation(), methodSymbol.Name);

        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
    }
```

И регистрировать его иначе:

```
    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression);
    }
```